# I Can't Make Customized Icon to be bigger on Desktop Window 11

Tags: icons

[I try to View>Large Icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9AneH.png)

[and Small Icons either but it's the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ia2uD.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How have you constructed the icons and for which resolution or resolutions?

Comment: Icons have multiples image sizes included within the icon file, so that specific icon likely doesn't have an icon image size larger than that - you can create an icon with larger sizes, however the resolution of the icon will be poor since it'll pixelate from not having a higher resolution image as it goes up in size